# strtok() returns NULL on subsequent calls even though there are more tokens to be read

Tags: c, struct, tokenize, strtok, string.h

I'm having an issue in my program where calling strtok(NULL, "\r\n"); returns a NULL after I made a function call even though there are still tokens in the stream. I've looked over this for a while and can't figure out what it is about this function call that changes the behaviour of subsequent `strtok()` calls.

I'd be really grateful to anyone who can help. Cheers.

Main function:

```
int main() 
{ 
    char raw[] = "0 4 96 30\r\n3 4 64 60\r\n3 5 64 20\r\n3 2 32 40\r\n5 1 100 20\r\n20 3 4 30\r\n"; 

    char* line = strtok(raw, "\r\n");            //line == "0 4 96 30" OK
    line = strtok(NULL, "\r\n");                 //line == "3 4 64 60" OK
    line = strtok(NULL, "\r\n");                 //line == "3 5 64 20" OK
    struct Process current = parseProcess(line); //Now strtok calls after this will return NULL...
    line = strtok(NULL, "\r\n");                 //line == NULL (supposed to be "3 2 32 40")
    line = strtok(NULL, "\r\n");                 //line == NULL

    return 0; 
}
```

The struct and function used:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h> 

struct Process {
    long timeArrived;
    long processId;
    long memorySizeReq;
    long jobTime;
    long remainingTime;
};

//Rips values from the input and puts it into a struct
struct Process parseProcess(char* input){
    struct Process output;

    //Makes a back up as to not mutate input
    char* temp = malloc(strlen(input) * sizeof(char));
    strcpy(temp, input);
    char* token = strtok(temp, " ");

    //Fills out the fields of the parsed output
    for(int i=0; i<4; i++){
        switch(i){
            case 0:
                output.timeArrived = atoi(token);
                token = strtok(NULL, " ");
                break;
            case 1:
                output.processId = atoi(token);
                token = strtok(NULL, " ");
                break;
            case 2:
                output.memorySizeReq = atoi(token);
                token = strtok(NULL, " ");
                break;
            case 3:
                output.jobTime = atoi(token);
                output.remainingTime = atoi(token);
                token = strtok(NULL, " ");
                break;
        }
    }
    return output;
}
```

Comment: You nest different `strtok()` "methods"... one in `main()` and another in `parceProcess()`. `strtok()` is not reentrant, maybe try [`strtok_r()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strtok.html), if you´re on a POSIX system.

Comment: `strtok` is not being re-entered, so re-entrancy is not the issue. Its inability to parse two different strings concurrently is the problem. However, using `strtok_r` (with two different states/contexts) does address the problem.

Comment: it says that strtok_r() is implicitly declared even though i compiled with -std=c99 and with <string.h> included (I tried it with -std=gnu99 too). I'm on a windows machine if that makes a difference.

Comment: The string processing is terrible, sorry. Why use strtok at all? That's only necessary if you must create tokens of different types (e.g. numbers, words, operators etc.) which you do not know in advance. Here you have lines with numbers, and as it looks, always the same number count per line. Simply read for numbers with (s)scanf, using `%n` as a means to keep track of the read position in the string. You probably don't even need to separate the input in lines at all. Instead of 40 lines or so you'd have 4, no dynamic memory, no parsing logic.

Answer (score 1):

`strtok` is not reentrant and is used inside `parseProcess` so the next calls in `main` use a different context. Furthermore `strtok(raw, "\r\n");` considers both `'\r'` and `'\n'` as separators as well as any sequence of these characters, the consequence of this is `strtok()` won't return empty tokens for empty lines in the source string.

Regarding POSIX [`strtok_r`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok_r), following the comments, it does not work in windows, you do, however, have [`strtok_s`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok). There are other ways to do this, but given that you are using `strtok()` here is an example of this could be implemented:

[Live demo](https://rextester.com/UVO54379)

```
struct Process parseProcess(char* input){
    struct Process output; 
    char* temp = malloc(strlen(input) + 1); //notes 1, 2, 3
    strcpy(temp, input);   
    char* strmax; //for **stmax parameter
    char* token = strtok_r(temp, " ", &strmax);
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        switch(i){
            case 0:
                output.timeArrived = atoi(token);
                token = strtok_r(NULL, " ", &strmax);
                break;
            case 1:
                output.processId = atoi(token);
                token = strtok_r(NULL, " ", &strmax);
                break;
            case 2:
                output.memorySizeReq = atoi(token);
                token = strtok_r(NULL, " ", &strmax);
                break;
            case 3:
                output.jobTime = atoi(token);
                output.remainingTime = atoi(token);
                token = strtok_r(NULL, " ", &strmax);
                break;
        }
    }
    free(temp);   //free the allocated memory
    return output;    
}
```

Notes:

1. Reserve space for null terminator when you allocate with `strlen`.
2. Memory allocation is expensive, if you can, avoid it, in this case you could use `char temp[strlen(input) + 1];`.

   **MSVC** quibles with this because it's a variable lenght arrays and says it's an error, it's not, VLAs are valid in C, you can use **gcc** or **clang** compilers, if you want to use them.
3. `sizeof(char)` is not needed, char is 1 byte across platforms.

```
//...
#ifdef _MSC_VER  //improved portability
    #define strtok_r strtok_s
#endif 

int main() 
{   
    char raw[] = "0 4 96 30\r\n3 4 64 60\r\n3 5 64 20\r\n3 2 32 40\r\n5 1 100 20\r\n20 3 4 30\r\n"; 
    char* strmax;
    char* line = strtok_r(raw, "\r\n", &strmax);            //line == "0 4 96 30" OK                                 
    line = strtok_r(NULL, "\r\n", &strmax);                 //line == "3 4 64 60" OK
    line = strtok_r(NULL, "\r\n", &strmax);                 //line == "3 5 64 20" OK                                   
    struct Process current = parseProcess(line); 
    line = strtok_r(NULL, "\r\n", &strmax);                 //line == "3 2 32 40" OK                                  
    line = strtok_r(NULL, "\r\n", &strmax);                 ///line == "5 1 100 20" OK;

    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Note that Microsoft's version of `strtok_s` has exactly the same semantics as POSIX `strtok_r`, but the function `strtok_s` defined in the Annex K of the C Standard has a different prototype and behavior. I would suggest not using functions from Annex K and defining `strtok_r` for the Windows environment  either as a macro `#define strtok_r  strtok_s` or as a function with the appropriate semantics.

Comment: @chqrlie, I added it, do you think it's enough?

Comment: No, I would not do it this way: I would stay away from Annex K because of these incompatibilities and because of the uncanny semantics in case of constraint violations. Hence I would not use `__STDC_LIB_EXT1__`. The way I see it is `#ifdef _MSC_VER #define strtok_r strtok_s #endif` and always use `strtok_r`. `strtok_r` is declared in `<string.h>` on POSIX systems and `strtok_s` too on Microsoft systems.

Comment: @chqrlie, I see. The usage of strtok_s in main was just because I forgot to change it.